# Flash export Movie to SWC, load and play it in Flex ActionScript Project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, swc

I can not run AS included into SWC library. I made two test-projects - one in Flash Pro - just as it was described in the answer here:

[the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712478/imported-swc-movie-clip-not-being-displayed-flash-builder)

- with addition of some AS3 code that animate the blue circle. Second project - Flex ActionScript Mobile project type in Flash Builder.

I exported the Flash Pro project to SWC, with "AS Linkage" box and "Export In Frame 1" boxes checked. 
Then I add the SWC to Flex project in project properties. I add MovieClip to the Stage:

package
{

```
import ExportSWC_test_fla.*;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class BlueCircleRun extends Sprite
{
    public function BlueCircleRun()
    {
        super();

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var symbol:BlueCircle = new BlueCircle();

        symbol.x = 150;

        symbol.y = 150;

        addChild(symbol);

    }
}
```

}

I can see the MovieClip on the stage - when I
compile and run Flex project. The problem is - the script in the Movie does not run. How can I run it ? Can I import and run the whole Movie from SWC ? How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(symbol as MovieClip).play();
```

Comment: @SergoKalandadze I use this exact code in my Mobile Game to start the animation of a MovieClip.  I'm unclear why it wouldn't work for you.  If you can expand, perhaps I can offer more assistance.

Comment: Thank You very much Flextras, the code above come from very short example - here is a code that is placed on MovieClip timeline, the code I am trying to play: